FamilyActivityPicker on iOS Simulator not populating apps
I'm looking to make an app using the ScreenTime API and the Managed Settings framework. I'm experimenting with the FamilyActivityPicker, but when I open it from the simulator I see only categories with no applications.
Without being able to select applications, I cannot test properly the app.
I can't install it on a real device to test it because I do not have a paid Apple Developer account and therefore can't access the capability if I select my Free Developer Account in order to install it on my iPhone.
Tried everything but can't figure out a solution.

I had the same issue, building and running in the physical device solved the problem for me.


That first website in the list...
